# CSV headers to MySQL columns automatically using python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv

I want to add CSV data to MySQL using python, but i want automatically create columns in the mysql table using columns of csv

Is there any way to create column of MySQL table with CSV using python automatically more than 100 columns in CSV

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to create a table in MySQL (or any other database: PostgreSQL, SQLite,.. ) based on a .csv header (columns names) is by using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) combined.

First of all, you need to install those two libraries :

```
pip install pandas
pip install sqlalchemy
```

Considering the `.csv` below (4 columns) :

[image]

Secondly, by running this code, you will be able to create a table named `test_table` with the types defined in the variable/list `type_cols`.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@server/database') #Put here your credentials

df = pd.read_csv('csv_sql.csv') #Change the parameters to match your csv properties

type_cols = ['DATE', 'INTEGER', 'TEXT', 'REAL'] #Put here the columns types
name_cols = df.columns.tolist()
table_config= ', '.join([' '.join(map(str, i)) for i in zip(name_cols, type_cols)])

engine.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table ({table_config})''')
```

If necessary, you can retrieve a dataframe by running this :

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM test_table", engine) #Change the query to match your needs
print(df)

col1    col2    col3    col4
```